# Remove all but specified substring from string

Tags: c#, string

I have a string that contains several instances of a substring, as well as other text. The substring is specified by beginning with a given sequence of letters (e.g. CNTY) and ending with a double slash (//). How could I efficiently remove all text that does not fall inside the specified substring? Thanks for the help. I found that this Regex will return the result needed:

```
string result = Regex.Matches(text, "CNTY(.*)//").Cast<Match>().Aggregate("", (s, t) => s + t.Value, s => s);
```

But, I have another more complicated substring, which begins with WEATHLOC, then contains wildcard text across several lines, and ends with a line beginning RMKS, more wildcard text, and then //. Here is an example:

WEATHLOC/ICAO:KCOS//
OBSTIME/052005Z//
WIND/360/10//
VSBY/10/SM//
CLDLYR/-/LYR:BKN//
TEMP/MAXTEMP:15/MINTEMP:18//
ALTSTG/HG:29.92//
RMKS/SAMPLE//

Everything from WEATHLOC to the final // needs to be captured, and I can only rely on its beginning with WEATHLOC and ending with RMKS*//. Is there a way to express that in a Regex match?

Comment: Use regex to extract all instances of the substring.

Comment: It sounds like you need to look into [Regular Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions).

Comment: [Here](https://regexone.com/references/csharp)'s a more straightforward tutorial.

Comment: One of the few cases where I would recommend a regex, e.g. `CNTY.*?//`. Could you rework your question into a [mcve] (i.e. add some example input/output, edge cases, etc.)? It's kind of expected here.

Comment: I need to get better with Regex. I had CNTY.?// and couldn't get it to work :(

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
string text = "hiCNTYhello//content What /-CNTYworld//12texCNTY!//That's it";
string search = "CNTY(.*?)//";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, search);
```

Will match "hello", "world" and "!"

Comment: The `()` are there to capture the inner text between the beginning and end markers. But perhaps I misunderstood the question... If the whole substring is required, including the markers, then I guess you're right.

Comment: I would suggest adding some code (LINQ?) to collect the values into a new single `string`.

Answer (score -1):

This little code segment works. The RegEx method was too difficult for me, but this does work. We are trying to check if we are in bounds of CNTY // and to output that text to the StringBuilder.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var input = @"CNTYTestingTesting//This is some more test CNTY1234//And some moreCNTYWhat is this?//";
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    int inCnty = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i ++)
    {
        // Test for start
        if (i < input.Length - 4)
        {
            if (input.Substring(i, 4) == "CNTY")
            {
                inCnty = i + 4; // Index of first CNTY
            }
        }

        // Test for end
        if (i < input.Length - 1)
        {
            if (input.Substring(i, 2) == @"//")
            {
                inCnty = -1; // Reset
            }
        }

        // Test if we are in the segment
        if (i >= inCnty && inCnty > 0)
        {
            // Outside string
            sb.Append(input[i]);
        }

    }

    var output = sb.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(output);
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: This would also include everything after the last `CNTY` even if there is no matching `//` after it.

Comment: I understand it would, and that's a possible boundary case? Doesn't seem like the data would have a CNTY without a matching // because it sounds like this is a delimiting string CNTY....//   It would need to be checked for. But if there is an assumption that the data always conformed to CNTY must have a closing // then the code works.